# How do I iterate and index a List of Lists in OGNL/Struts2?

Tags: struts2, ognl

I have a property with a profile like this:

```
public List<List<String>> getAvailablePassengersJS()
```

I wish to create a table with one row for each element in the outer List, and a column for each of the first five positions in the inner List.
I tried using this:

```
<s:iterator value="ssn.docked.AvailablePassengersJS" var="line">
<tr>
    <td><s:property value="line[0]"/></td>
    <td><s:property value="line[1]"/></td>
    <td><s:property value="line[2]"/></td>
    <td><s:property value="line[3]"/></td>
    <td><s:property value="line[4]"/></td>
</tr>
</s:iterator>
```

However, the output is 100+ rows of entirely blank columns:

```
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

I know the data is correctly populated. When I do this:

```
<s:iterator value="ssn.docked.AvailablePassengersJS" var="line">
<tr>
    <td><s:property/></td>
</tr>
</s:iterator>
```

I get 100+ rows like this:

```
<tr>
    <td>[2236, Middle, Onbenbosin Bawed, true, You can book Tritho Fonand]</td>
</tr>
```

And when I do this:

```
<s:iterator value="ssn.docked.AvailablePassengersJS" var="line">
<tr>
    <td><s:property value="line"/></td>
</tr>
</s:iterator>
```

I get an exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList incompatible with java.lang.String
```

So I know "line" resolves to an ArrayList. [Everything I've read about OGNL](http://commons.apache.org/ognl/language-guide.html) seems to imply that I should be able to index an array via the [] notation. I've tried  more combinations of {}, #, etc, that I won't burden you with to no avail.
Can anyone explain why this doesn't work and what I need to do to make it work?

**UPDATE**

Trying Quaternion's suggestion below I used this code:

```
<s:iterator value="ssn.docked.AvailablePassengersJS" var="line">
<tr id="availPass<s:property value="#line[0]"/>">
    <td><s:property value="#line[1]"/></td>
    <td><s:property value="#line[2]"/></td>
    <td><s:checkbox key="#line[3]" value="false" theme="simple"/>&nbsp;Book</td>
</tr>
</s:iterator>
```

It **mostly** works. Unfortunately it fails for the checkbox:

```
<tr id="availPass151570">
    <td>Low</td>
    <td>Andadicko Ostan</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="#line[3]" value="true" id="#line_3_"/><input type="hidden" id="__checkbox_#line_3_" name="__checkbox_#line[3]" value="true" />&nbsp;Book</td>
</tr>
```

If I don't use key, no combination of id or value works either.
If I just both name and id:

```
<td><s:checkbox name="#line[3]" id="#line[3]" value="false" theme="simple"/>&nbsp;Book</td>
```

if doesn't resolve it:

```
<td><input type="checkbox" name="Book" value="true" id="#line3"/><input type="hidden" id="__checkbox_#line3" name="__checkbox_Book" value="true" /></td>
```

If I just use name:

```
<td><s:checkbox name="#line[3]" value="false" theme="simple"/>&nbsp;Book</td>
```

it doesn't work either:

```
<td><input type="checkbox" name="#line[3]" value="true" id="#line_3_"/><input type="hidden" id="__checkbox_#line_3_" name="__checkbox_#line[3]" value="true" />&nbsp;Book</td>
```

if I just use id, I get some internal error:

```
    <td><s:checkbox id="#line[3]" value="false" theme="simple"/>&nbsp;Book</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="<!-- FREEMARKER ERROR MESSAGE STARTS HERE -->...
Expression parameters.name is undefined on line 23, column 32 in template/simple/checkbox.ftl.
The problematic instruction:
----------
==> ${parameters.name?html} [on line 23, column 30 in template/simple/checkbox.ftl]
```

Why does the parameter for checkbox require a different syntax than for property?

Comment: I can't tell what is being asked, will reverse down vote if question is clarified with (tried) - (produced) - (but required). The what is required is missing there is just a big tag soup.

Comment: Quaternion fails to mention the long thread of back-and-forth asking for information he deleted which left the question in the above state... My conclusion is that if someone who reputation is in the top 4% can't succinctly answer a simple question to someone who has been in the field for 25 years then the technology isn't ready for prime time. I'll stick to Struts-1 until Struts-2 can be adapted to my needs (rather than having to adapt my needs to Struts-2).

Comment: Have you done anything to improve the question? You are doing nothing complicated, I'm sure anything you want can be easily answered/done.  I already explained: How the struts2 checkbox works is independent from how iteration works. I took the time to answer the original question and then the question changed. It's like me asking how does a java for-each loop work and then getting mad that it does not explain my nested printf function. Other struts2 answers are going to read this and think, this makes no sense. Also questions are free, if you ask the wrong question just ask another.

Answer (score 1):

```
private List<List<String>> listOfLists;

public List<List<String>> getListOfLists() {
    return listOfLists;
}

public void setListOfLists(List<List<String>> listOfLists) {
    this.listOfLists = listOfLists;
}




    <s:iterator var="list" value="%{listOfLists}">
        <s:iterator var="list" value="#list" status="stat">
              <s:property value="#list[#stat.index]"/> //by index.
        </s:iterator><br/>
    </s:iterator>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I do not want to iterate over the inner list. I want to index into it. Your function runs, and displays all values. But it does not give me what I asked for. I wish to index into the inner list so I can pull out specific values. Some will be for IDs, others for display, others for hover messages.

Comment: Do you want access the inner list by index?

Answer (score 0):

It's an old question but for others, you need to use `%{listname[index]}"` for checkbox e.g.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="%{#line_3_[1]}" value="true" id="%{#line_3_[1]}"/>
```